# Change Linetype of geom_hline Without Changing the Legend Title

Tags: ggplot2, geom-hline

I am pretty new to R so please excuse me if I got this wrong.
I am trying to change a dashed linetype of a `geom_hline` in ggplot2 to a solid one.
Any help is much appreciated!

Usually this is easily done with changing `linetype = "dashed"` to `linetype = "solid"`. But since I have to use linetype for the text in my legend I cannot do this. Also adding `linetype = "solid"` after color results in

> Error in [[<-.data.frame (*tmp*, i, value = c("blue", "blue")) : 
>     Replacement has 2 lines, Data has 1`

This is the code that I am trying to adjust:

```
geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 5, linetype = "Title 1"), colour = "blue") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 2, linetype = "Title 2"), colour = "blue") +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "", values = c(2, 2),
                        guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(color = c("blue", "blue"))))
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible working example with your entire `ggplot` call and data, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/882102

Comment: Have you tried `scale_linetype_manuaL(name = "", values = c(1,1), ...)` ?

Comment: What do you mean with Have you tried 'scale_linetype_manuaL(name = "", values = c(1,1), ...)' ? That's what I am using!

Comment: This is the plot I am using
'ggplot(data,aes(one, two, color = high)) + geom_point(shape=19, size = 5, alpha=0.8, position=position_jitter(width=.1,height=.01)) + jitter scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))'